# Why the float values are different from double values when set precision?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why the float values are different from double values when set precision on  std::cout   ??

```
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << endl;
    float num = 1.2;
    cout <<  num << endl;
    double num2 = 1.2;
    cout <<  num2 << endl;
```

Output:

```
1.2000000476837158203
1.1999999999999999556
```

Comment: Will it be 'cause the math-precision of the float is different from the double?

Double: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Float: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @moooeeeep: Damn, that's a better duplicate. Shall I reopen, and you close as dupe to that one?

Comment: According to the story I would say more than double is super-set of float! ;)

Comment: I've reopened, so someone can close against the other duplicate.

Comment: Different isn't the same. -- Fred Picker